# The name 'f_name' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am c#.net newbie.  This is my form table.

```
First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="f_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnInsertion" runat="server" Text="Insert" 
OnClick="btnInsertion_Click"  />
```

I need help on solving this two error in visual basic.  This is my xxxx.aspx.cs which giving me two CS0103 error
-f_name does not exist in the context. 
-txtFname does not exist in the context.

```
protected void btnInsertion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection())
        {

        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
            connection.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into student_folio values(@f_name)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(@f_name, txtFname.Text));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        txtFname.Text = "";            s

        }

}
```

Comment: The parameter name should be in double quotes `"@f_name"` otherwise it's looking for a variable with the name `@f_name`.  As for `txtFname` that means it's not defined in a scope where you can get to it from that method.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have forgotten to enclose `@f_name` in `Parameters.Add(`, also txtFname is not within the scope, is it existing on the page you are accessing `btnInsertion`?

```
protected void btnInsertion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection())
        {

        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
            connection.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into student_folio (fieldname) values(@f_name)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("f_name", txtFname.Text));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        txtFname.Text = "";

        }

}
```

Comment: CS0103 is a compilation error because `@f_name` is not defined as a variable.  Any issues with the SQL would be run time exceptions and you can do an insert without listing the column names if you include values for all columns, though it's definitely better if you do include them always.

Comment: ahh, sorry, in his code, he forgot to enclose @f_name with "", changed it